# Why does Trace.WriteLine("Test") not appear when targeting .net 4.0 but does when 3.5

Tags: .net-4.0

I have just noticed that when i call the following code from a console app

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  Trace.WriteLine("Logging");
  Debug.WriteLine("Logging Debug");
}
```

if I am targeting .net 4.0 no messages appear in the debugview app although I am capturing all outputs.

If I change to target 3.5 it appears fine.

What's changed and how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make DebugView work under .NET 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429254/how-to-make-debugview-work-under-net-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually by design.
From [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/457063/outputdebugstring-doesnt-work-in-the-debugger-vs-2010-pro-beta-1-c) :

> The CLR has a new debugging
>   architecture where the CLR is native
>   debugging the application even when
>   managed only attached, and therefore
>   MS-SysInternals DebugView will not
>   work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this on the same machine?

It could be that the debug viewer (assumed DbgView from Sysinternals) is not connected. Check the title of the debug viewer for the name of the machine you're connected to.

Comment: I have debugview loaded at the time when i am switching between 4 and 3.5 and its appearing for 3.5

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me:

```
Trace.Autoflush = true;
```