# debugView showing no stderr output

Tags: c#, dll, stderr, debugview

I am running debugView under VS2010 on Win 7 64bit.  I have a c# app that calls a c dll.  I have some fprintf(stderr) statements in my C dll, and some Console.Error writeLine statements in my c# code, but none of them show up in DebugView.  In my VS2010 I tried writing the output  to the Output window, and then tried the Immediate window, and still nothing shows.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there something about c# and a dll that precludes output?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known problem:
http://bembengarifin.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/debugtrace-output-is-not-being-captured-by-debugview-when-vs2010-in-debug-mode/

The solution is to write your own...not a very appealing proposition!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Capture Win32 and Capture Global Win32 selected in the Capture menu?

Do Trace.WriteLine() C# statements output to debugview?

Comment: Yes CaptureWin32 selected, but not Global.  I can't set Global on because "access is denied"

Comment: You get an "access is denied" error when you try to turn on Global in DebugView? Are you logged in as a local administrator?

Comment: No, but I have admin privileges.

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue with access rights in general. Are you on a corporate network, or is it your local machine? If you're on a network, speak to your administrator... as I originally asked, does Trace.WriteLine() output to DebugView?

Comment: I re-ran program explicitly with admin privileges, and no diff.  I should add that I'm getting lots of System output; just nothing from my c# or DLL code

Comment: Trade.WriteLine("mesg")  does not output to DebugView either.

Comment: Create a simple console app and put some System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine() statements in it, just to check that it's nothing to do with your application. If they don't come out in DebugView, check your advanced permissions, event log and .Net logs. I can't really suggest any more than that, sorry!

Comment: I'm connected via Remote Desktop to a computer that is 10 feet away, but doing things directly (ie, without RDP) still no diff

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429254/how-to-make-debugview-work-under-net-4   and   http://bembengarifin.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/debugtrace-output-is-not-being-captured-by-debugview-when-vs2010-in-debug-mode/