# SendMessage not working in VS release mode

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sendmessage

Using Visual Studio, I’ve developed a Windows Forms app that communicates with another app via SendMessage(). After much head scratching it now works well in debug mode.

But when I switch to release mode it doesn’t work at all. According to DebugView the messages simply aren’t sent. I can’t see any error messages and I’ve tried running the .exe with elevated privileges but no joy.

Before I set about creating a minimal project to demonstrate this phenomenon, does anyone have the explanation? Or ideas to try because I’m stumped.

Windows 11, .Net Framework 4.8.1, Visual Studio 2019, VB.net.

I guess one simple solution is to distribute it in debug!

Comment: In Release mode you will not get any debug info. Your code might actually work correctly in Release mode.

Comment: You calling `SendMessage()` to send what message to what? Post your code, the function declaration, and include enough context to understand how / when this function is called and what it's called for

Comment: Thanks but firstly I can see that my code doesn't work correctly because DebugView shows the messages being sent in debug mode and no messages in release mode.

Comment: Thanks but firstly I can see that my code doesn't work correctly because DebugView shows the messages being sent in debug mode and no messages in release mode. Secondly, in order to post my code I need to spend several hours developing a simple demo. I was hoping to avoid that. Finally, I've discovered that neither the debug exe nor the release exe send messages when executed 'standalone'. Only debug works when executed under the shelter of VS. I guess I better get working on that demo. Or abandon the project. Sad face emoji.

Comment: But if I run the debug exe as an administrator it works but not so with the release mode.

Comment: The [doc to Sysinternals DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) says: *"DebugView is an application that lets you monitor debug output ..."*, but when running in Release mode you won't get any debug output! This may also be the case when you run the application as standalone, because then, no debugger is attached. You must make a little test app which receives the message.

Comment: Thanks but I suggest that 'debug' in the DebugView context refers to the activity of debugging in general rather than just within VS. As proof, if you run DebugView with VS not open you still get messages logged. I have no need for a test app, I have a working app. When my app run as admin sends it messages, it sends replies which my app picks up and processes. This is confirmed by DebugView. But when run not as admin, DebugView logs nothing sent by my app. So I feel all this is fairly conclusive evidence that this is a settings thing that no amount of examining code is going to resolve.

Comment: @Cap'nCreer Do the parts of the apps run under different Windows accounts depending on if you've set debug or release? Maybe it's an account priviliges problem.

Comment: Nope, all under the same account.

Comment: I just found the question [How to make DebugView work under .NET 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4429254/880990) having answers giving a very useful insight into how DebugView works.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I resorted to setting up a new project, adding the form from the original project, renaming the root namespace and it worked perfectly in both debug and release! No code changes.

What can I say except thank you for your comments.